# window.open multiple setintervals images loops

Tags: javascript, loops, setinterval, window.open

I'm having 3 issues with my Intervals.

One is my internal only show two pictures, and Ι am trying to show 4. I attempted to duplicate my function and change the `<img />` into the `doc.write(didn't work)`.

Last, how do I create a loop out of those intervals (showing 1,2,3,4) nostop. It needs to be displaying all image into window.open. (Any advice: Is it better to create an Array of `<img />`?)

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    var OpenWindow = window.open("http://vrjournal.com/adtech-new-york-showcases-virtual-realitys-move-into-mobile-advertising","","top=100, left=400,resizable=yes,height=550,width=550,menubar=yes,location=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes");

    Update1();
    function Update1() {
        OpenWindow.document.write("<IMG float:'center' SRC='Oculus.jpg'>");
        setInterval("Update2();",3000);
    }

    function Update2() {
        OpenWindow.document.write("<IMG float:'center' SRC='future-vr.jpg'>");
        setInterval("Update1();",3000);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Browser will not allow you to write on a cross domain web page window.

Comment: @TasosK. thanks for the correction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the window you are opening is on the same domain as the page your code is in, then you can create an array of image URLs and advance an index into the URL on each timer.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    var OpenWindow = window.open("http://vrjournal.com/adtech-new-york-showcases-virtual-realitys-move-into-mobile-advertising","","top=100, left=400,resizable=yes,height=550,width=550,menubar=yes,location=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes");

    var imgURLS = ['Oculus.jpg', 'future-vr.jpg', 'img3.jpg', 'img4.jpg'];
    var imgIndex = 0;

    var timer = setInterval(function() {
        if (imgIndex >= imgURLS.length) {
            // done with the array of images, stop the timer
            clearInterval(timer);
        } else {
            OpenWindow.document.write('<img src ="' + imgURLS[imgIndex++] +  '">');
        }
    }, 3000);

</script>
```

If the window you opened is in a different domain than the page your code is in, then because of same-origin security protections, the browser will not let you modify the other window.

Comment: what do you mean by advance an index ?

Comment: @Sow - Code example added.

Comment: what does var imgIndex = 0; do? is it referring to the Array imgUrls?

Comment: @Sow - `var imgIndex = 0;` just creates a Javascript variable named `imgIndex` and assigns it an initial value of `0`.  That variable is then used later in the code to access one of the items in the `imgURLS` array.  This is very basic Javascript syntax.  If this is not familiar to you, I would suggest you work through a beginning Javascript tutorial either online or in a book.  It will save you a lot of time.

Comment: oki dok.. this where the loops is set... If you change it for an number it will select or deselect that image to be show?

Comment: why the image are stacking below each others? beside stacking over each other images?

Comment: @Sow - `imgIndex` is incremented each time the timer fires.  That's what the `imgIndex++` does.  For controlling the format of the images you have to apply appropriate HTML/CSS formatting to position the images.

Comment: @Sow - I have no idea what your last comment means.  My code will iterate over all of the items in the array (adding one more each 3 seconds when the interval timer fires) and then stop when it gets to the last item in the array.

Comment: Thanks ! I see. for creating the loops of infinity images does extra loop codes need to be add to var timer or imgIndex?                                                for (var imgIndex = 0; j < timer.length; j++)
   {
   for (var imgIndex = 0; i < timer.length; i++)} is it right?

Comment: @Sow - I don't know what you're trying to do.  Rather that show me code, please explain in words what you are trying to accomplish. `timer` is not an array so I have no idea why you're using `timer.length`.  That will not work.  What does "infinity images" mean?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i'm trying to do generate an infinite loop for those images.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
        var OpenWindow = window.open("","","top=100, left=400,resizable=yes,height=550,width=550,menubar=yes,location=yes,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes");

        var imgURLS = ['Oculus.jpg', 'future-vr.jpg', 'morpheus.jpg', 'samsungvr.jpg'];
        var imgIndex = {
      for (var i = 0; i < imgURLS.length; i++) { 
        for (var j = 0; j < imgURLS.length; j++)
    };

        var timer = setInterval(function() {
            if (imgIndex > imgURLS.length) {
                clearInterval(timer);
            } else {
                OpenWindow.document.write('<img src ="' + imgURLS[imgIndex++] +  '">');
            }
        }, 3000);

        </script>
```

Comment: The proper procedure here is that you only submit an answer if it's actually an answer.  If you just want to share code, you can use the "edit" button to add it to your question, not put it in an answer.  Since your original question appears to now be answered, if this is a new question you should post a new question and in that question you should describe in WORDs what you are trying to accomplish.  Your code does not describe what you are trying to do.

Comment: You've done the wrong thing.  You do NOT change your existing question into a new question.  That breaks everything here because your original question already has an answer and your original question should STAY that way.  You should put your original question back the way it was.  Then, you can make a NEW question.